# Does every closed subset in a scheme correspond to a unique closed subscheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Could anyone give an example of a closed subset $Y$ in a scheme $X$,
such that there is no closed immersion from a scheme into $X$ whose "image of underlying points" is $Y$?

Also, could anyone give an example $Y$ that admits more than one "realization" as a closed subscheme of $X$?

Comment: by closed in your first question you mean Zariski closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every closed subset can be made into a closed subscheme, e.g. by choosing the reduced structure (see for example [tag 01J3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3) in the stacks project). This would be the canonical choice of a scheme structure on the given closed subset, but there are many more in general (see below for an example).

Regarding your second question:
Just take for example $X = \mathbb{A}^1_x$ and the closed subschemes $Y = V(x) = \text{Spec}(k[x]/(x))$ and $Y' = V(x^2) = \text{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))$. In this case $Y$ is the reduction of $Y'$. Higher powers of $x$ all define closed subschemes of $\mathbb{A}^1$ with the same underlying topological space (which is just the origin). Here you can already see that there are plenty such subschemes.

In classical algebraic geometry one is (depending on the settup...) not necessarily able to distinguish these subschemes (subvarieties), but they occur very naturally (you would certainly want to know multiplicities of roots of a given polynomial instead of just knowing the set of roots). This is one of the reasons for introducing structure sheaves. They are in this regard so to say the glasses we need to see properly.

Comment: When citing the Stacks Project, it is preferred to cite the tag number - this is a four -character code which is guaranteed to never change, while a number like "lemma 26.12.4" may end up referring to a different result as the Stacks Project grows and changes.

Comment: Which is [tag 01J3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3), for reference.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I agree. I was writing the answer too quickly and simply did not pay much attention. Thanks for reminding me though!